# Spark streaming batches stopping and waiting for GC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming

I have got a simple spark streaming job. It reads event from Kafka topic, does simple event transformation (eg. replace some characters with another ones) and sends transformed events to second Kafka topic. Everything works OK for some time (1 – 1.5 h) and after that we see that batches are scheduled (see screen below) and waiting to run. The pause takes about 5-6 minutes and this time GC is working and cleaning memory. After that everything works OK, but sometimes processing stops and in logs we see errors like that (see stack trace below). Please advise what Spark / Java parameters should be set to avoid this GC overhead.
Spark jobs are scheduled every 10 sec., one batch execution takes about 5 sec.

**Stack trace**

```
2017-09-21 11:26:15 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 33.0 in stage 115.0 (TID 4699, work8, executor 6): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.createFetchRequests(Fetcher.java:724)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.sendFetches(Fetcher.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1042)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:995)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.poll(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017-09-21 11:26:15 INFO  TaskSetManager:54 - Lost task 37.0 in stage 115.0 (TID 4702) on work8, executor 6: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (GC overhead limit exceeded) [duplicate 1]
2017-09-21 11:26:15 INFO  TaskSetManager:54 - Lost task 26.0 in stage 115.0 (TID 4695) on work8, executor 6: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (GC overhead limit exceeded) [duplicate 2]
```

**Parameters of spark – submit**

```
spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --executor-cores 8 \
  --executor-memory 20g \
  --driver-memory 20g \
  --num-executors 4 \
  --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g" \
  --conf "spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate=1125" \
  --conf "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=1125" \
```

[image: Statistics]

```
//Job
    val sendToKafka = KafkaSender.sendToKafka(spark, kafkaServers, outputTopic, kafkaEnabled) _
    val stream = KafkaUtils
      .createDirectStream(ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](inputTopics, kafkaParams))

    stream.foreachRDD { statementsStreamBatch =>
      val offsetRanges = statementsStreamBatch.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

      if (!statementsStreamBatch.isEmpty) {

        val inputCsvRDD = statementsStreamBatch.map(_.value)

        var outputCsvRDD : RDD[String] = null

        if(enrichmerEnabled) {
          outputCsvRDD = Enricher.processStreaminputCsvRDD, enricherNumberOfFields)
        } else {
          outputCsvRDD = inputCsvRDD
        }
        sendToKafka(outputCsvRDD)
      }
      stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()

//Enricher
object Enricher {

  def processStream(eventStream: RDD[String], numberOfFields : Integer): RDD[String] = {

      eventStream.map(
        csv => if (csv.count(_ == ',') <= numberOfFields) {
          csv
        } else {
          csv.replaceAll(",(?=[^']*',)", "#")
        }
      )
  }

//KafkaSender 
object KafkaSender {

  def sendToKafka(spark: SparkSession, servers: String, topic: String, enabled: Boolean)(message: RDD[String]): Unit = {
    val kafkaSink = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(KafkaSink(getKafkaProperties(servers)))
    val kafkaTopic = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(topic)

      message.foreach(kafkaSink.value.send(kafkaTopic.value, _))
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like problem with your code. It may have leak or it might be creating too many objects.

Comment: I have added source code

Comment: I'm not sure that this will help, just a wild guess: did you try to replace broadcasting of kafkaTopic with just passing it as is to your method and replace broadcasting of KafkaSink with lazy initialization (one per RDD partition?)

Comment: Inpsired by this article I have used broadcasting https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html

Comment: Error in broadcating caused creation of many instances of kafka producents.